# Getting full detail of an email for a id

Tags: java, gmail, gdata-api, google-api-java-client

hi i am trying to get full detail of an email in gmail for getting feed  for incoming mail we have to call url
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ with request header
then i have to put encoded username and pass word of account like this
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));

i am writing my code in java after calling this url i am getting user's email feed but i want to know  about full details of a single email because summary element in feed is very short i want to get complete summary of an email i will get mail's id from this feed 
after getting id which url to call with what request headers or parameter for getting complete information about a particular email i am using clientlogin in this example.
here is code snippet

```
URL url2=new URL("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/");

        HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url2.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

      conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(("riteshmehandiratta1" + ":" + "shinderjeetji").getBytes()));

        conn.connect();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));



        String line;

        String contents = "";



        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

          contents += line;

        }


System.out.println(contents);
```

for getting feeds .this example work properly.
how to get an email detail?? please help...

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail Inbox feed only returns a subset of the email data and it should only be used to receive new email alerts:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed

If you want full control over the inbox, you should use IMAP:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview